# Deduce parameter type of pointer to member function template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, pointer-to-member

I'm trying to write a C++ function template `f` with one template parameter of type `void (Foo::*FUNC)(T const *)` where `Foo` is some class type. Furthermore, I would like to deduce `T` from the concrete member function pointer specified for `FUNC`. So one idea would be:

```
template<typename T, void(Foo::*FUNC)(T const *)>
void f()
{ /* use T in here, e.g. if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) */ }
```

But then I have to specify `T` explicitly when instantiating `f` and can't just write e.g. `f<&Foo::bar>`. I know there are ways to deduce the type of the first parameter of a function but they are all overly complicated (without using Boost). Is there a smarter way to do what i want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a trait to extract an argument from a member function pointer that looks like you expect it to look:

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename M> struct extract_arg;
    template<typename R, class C, typename A>
    struct extract_arg<R (C::*)(A const*)> { using type = A; }
}
```

And here's a C++17 function template with a non-type template parameter whose type is deduced from a placeholder:

```
template<auto FUNC>
void f()
{
    static_assert(std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(FUNC)>);
    using T = typename detail::extract_arg<decltype(FUNC)>::type;
    T t{};
}
```

It uses `std::is_member_function_pointer` to check its indeed of the correct type (well, family of types), and our helper trait to then extract `T`.

[See it live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FELyT749o2ILYW08).