# Can I deduce the argument types of a member function pointer template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member, template-argument-deduction

I often work with C-style libraries, where the callback-and-opaque-pointer pattern is common:

```
void callback(void *user_data, ...) { ... }

register_callback(callback, ptr_to_something_useful);
```

When working with such libraries from C++ land, I often find myself doing this:

```
struct my_type {
    static void static_callback(void *user_data) {
        reinterpret_cast<my_type *>(user_data)->callback();
    }
    void callback() { }
};

my_type foo;
register_callback(my_type::static_callback, &foo);
```

The `static_callback` can be a lambda... but I thought I'd be clever, and to eliminate some of the boilerplate, I defined the following C++ helper:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct dispatcher {
    template <void (T::*Func)(Args... args)>
    static void call(void *arg, Args... args) {
        T& obj = *reinterpret_cast<T *>(arg);
        (obj.*Func)(args...);
    }
};
```

Now I can omit `static_callback` and write:

```
register_callback(dispatcher<my_type>::call<&my_type::callback>, &foo);
```

Unfortunately, this gets ugly when the callback function takes several arguments (after the opaque user data pointer), because my helper requires me to explicitly specify both the class and argument types:

```
struct my_type {
    void callback(int a, char b, float c);
};

register_callback(dispatcher<my_type, int, char, float>::call<&my_type::callback>, &foo);
```

**So, can I do better?** I tried a few ways to get the compiler to somehow deduce the argument types in the parameter pack, but nothing has worked. The argument type parameter pack has to be defined somewhere before I can specify the non-type template parameter for the member function pointer. I have a feeling something might be possible with `auto` template parameters and/or [type traits to extract the argument types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66869212/deduce-parameter-type-of-pointer-to-member-function-template-parameter), but I haven't struck upon a working solution yet.

Answers may target any C++ standard version. If there's something for this in Boost I will accept that too (I can't use Boost in my current project, but I would love to look there to see how something's implemented.)

Here's a sort of "test bench" you can use to play around:

```
struct my_type {
    void callback(int, char, float) { }
};

void register_callback(void (*cb)(void *, int, char, float), void *user_data) {
    cb(user_data, 42, 'X', 3.14f);
}

int main() {
    my_type obj;
    register_callback(/* your magic here */, &obj);
}
```

Comment: Is it acceptable to invert control and have `magic_function<&my_type::callback> (&register_callback, &obj);` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt Upon further reflection - although I'd love to see that as an answer, and I can see how it makes the solution easier, I'd prefer a template that exposes a static function (no inversion). It's because sometimes callbacks aren't registered by calling a function, but by storing the static function pointer and user data pointer in a data structure. The inversion solution doesn't permit this use-case.

Comment: This simple version assumes the callback is named "callback". You can build on it to allow the callback to be named. (Template on the member function pointer instead of the object.) `template<typename T>struct magic{magic(T& obj) {} template<typename...Args> static void make_callback(void* p, Args...args) { ((T*)p)->callback(args...); }template<typename...Args> using StaticCallback = void(*)(void*, Args...); template<typename...Args> operator StaticCallback<Args...>() { return make_callback<Args...>; } }; register_callback(magic(obj), &obj);`

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks, but please post this as an answer so it (a) is legible and (b) can be properly voted and commented on!

Comment: You can post it as an answer if you are satisfied with it. It's not a complete solution because it hard-codes the name `callback`.

Comment: @TypeIA: The advantage of the inversion is that it avoids problems introduced by inheritance, where the actual object pointer is a different type from the class in the pointer-to-member-function.

Comment: The inversion would also allow the "magic" to detect whether the handler needs an `extern "C"` or `extern "C++"` modifier on the callback and introduce the corresponding free function.

Comment: @BenVoigt Points well taken... I'd love to see your solution (you'd get my upvote). But for my actual project I'll need to be able to directly store the free function pointer in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the pointer-to-member-function as a template parameter, then use a second type parameter to do the partial specialization on like so.

```
#include <iostream>

struct my_type {
    void callback(int i, char c, float f) {
        std::cout << i << " " << c << " " << f << "\n";
    }
};

void register_callback(void (*cb)(void *, int, char, float), void *user_data) {
    cb(user_data, 42, 'X', 3.14f);
}

template <auto Func, typename T = decltype(Func)>
struct dispatcher;

template <auto Func, typename Ret, typename Class, typename... Args>
struct dispatcher<Func, Ret (Class::*)(Args...)> {
    static void call(void* obj, Args... args) {
        (reinterpret_cast<Class*>(obj)->*Func)(args...);
    }
};

int main() {
    my_type obj;
    register_callback(&dispatcher<&my_type::callback>::call, &obj);
}
```

This can techically be misused by explicitly specifying the type parameter, but you could probably guard against that with some static asserts if it's needed.

Comment: Just beware that the expression `&obj` must have the same static type as `Class*` in the `Ret (Class::*)(Args...)`, or else the `reinterpret_cast` becomes undefined behavior.  No polymorphism allowed.

Comment: @BenVoigt Good point. My instinct was that there were some danger here that a static assert could sort out. My initial thought was probably redundant as misuse by explicitly specifying the parameter will result in a compile-time error. UB is much more nasty.

Comment: Very cool trick with the partial specialization. It works for me - thanks. I'll accept this answer after a reasonable time for others to chime in. (I don't need virtual calls in my use case, but this is a good limitation to take note of.)